# Transpose 6 columns with other columns identical

Tags: text-processing, awk, cut

I have the file like this...

```
a|b|c|d|e|1|2|3|4|5|f|g|h
```

I need the result as below

```
a|b|c|d|e|1|f|g|h  
a|b|c|d|e|2|f|g|h  
a|b|c|d|e|3|f|g|h  
a|b|c|d|e|4|f|g|h  
a|b|c|d|e|5|f|g|h
```

Basically I am trying to transpose 5 columns, with the rest of the columns repeated for each of those 5 attributes... (here values 1,2,3,4,5... in single row is being transposed into into 5 separate rows... in all those 5 rows, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h are duplicated.

Please help using AWK/SED/CUT anything.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'|' '{ for(i=6;i<=10;i++) print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$i,$11,$12,$13 }' OFS='|' file
```

The output:

```
a|b|c|d|e|1|f|g|h
a|b|c|d|e|2|f|g|h
a|b|c|d|e|3|f|g|h
a|b|c|d|e|4|f|g|h
a|b|c|d|e|5|f|g|h
```

---

- `for(i=6;i<=10;i++)` - iterating through the crucial fields

Comment: This worked !  Thank you very much !  However, I have 200 columns like this... it looks ugly to go on "print $1,$2... ,$200", is there a easy way to put it in a short form ?